# Create an MS-DOS disk

Tags: ms-dos

I want to make a bootable MS-DOS CD/DVD or floppy (not download it from other sites, I am sorry but I do not trust them). I currently only own an old pc with windows 98.

I also want this CD or floppy to be able to run from a computer which does not have windows but only Linux. And I would appreciate it if you would not tell me to install any additional  apps in order to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What part of the process are you stuck at?

Comment: You should consider using a tool like [Rufus](http://superuser.com/questions/617991/make-dos-games-and-dos-applications-as-bootable?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Create an msdos startup disk"](http://superuser.com/questions/580735/create-an-msdos-startup-disk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I currently only own an old pc with windows 98.

Go to "Add/Remove Programs" and select the "Startup disk" tab. Insert floppy. Press Start.

Alternatively: run `format /s a:` to reformat the disk and automatically copy a minimal MS-DOS environment to it.

Alternatively: run `sys a:` to write the boot record, then copy COMMAND.COM, IO.SYS, and whatever tools you need at the moment (FDISK, EDIT...)

The WinWorldPC website also has a collection of unmodified boot and install disks.

> I also want this CD or floppy to be able to run from a computer which does not have windows but only Linux.

It's a *boot disk*. The whole point of a boot disk is that it doesn't use the installed operating systems but boots the OS it has itself.

*However,* MS-DOS does not support reading from any of the filesystems that Linux normally uses, so you can't use it to fix your Linux configuration or read any of your Linux files. You'll need other tools for that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's also possible to create boot disk using regular formatting GUI. There's a checkbox for that.

Comment: ok. Now I want instead of a floppy  to use a DVD because I want to use this boot disk from a notebook which does not has floppy drive.

Comment: @TheLinuxGK: Now you're out of luck, because Windows 98 has no built-in support for writing CDs, much less embedding a boot image into one. You'd need [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).